# Android Development - layout of cards ( planning poker)

Tags: android

I was wondering what is the best layout to choose from if I am told to create an application that displays single cards to the user which he or she is able to choose from. For an example 10 cards will be laid out on the screen each with a different value. I have looked at both relative and linear layouts but I am kinda confused as I am coming from an iOS background. What is the best way to implement several buttons on the screen? Currently I have tried Image Buttons but it fills up the entire screen and I cannot find a way to shrink it. Any starting points will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should look into a [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) or [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

Those Links should be enough to get you started. Lemme know if you encounter any problems